# How can we generate this method using JCodeModel

Tags: java, code-generation, jcodemodel

I am using JCodeModel but cannot find how I can generate a method that returns a call from its super class.

Relevant parts of what I have ..

`JDefinedClass jc = jp._class("NewPremiumDTO");
JMethod m = jc.method(JMod.PUBLIC, LP.class, "map");
m.body()._return(m.body().invoke("super"). arg(JExpr.ref("map")));`

This will generate 2 lines rather than 1 like this

`super(map);
return super(map);`

inside generated method but I want to generate this

```
return super.map(map, this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m.body()._return(JExpr.invoke("super").invoke("map"). arg(JExpr.ref("map")).arg(JExpr._this()));
```